# Is there any way I can repair this PVC/conduit that carries sprinkler system wire from the ground into my garage?

Tags: repair, conduit, pvc

On the summer sun side of my house there is a small section of PVC that routes sprinkler wire from the yard into my garage where the rain bird controller is. After a decade or so of summer sun and one or two errant whacks with a weed eater it's broken.

I'd like to seal it back up with something more attractive and more durable than duct tape. I can't replace the pipe without pulling all the wire back through the wall then re-routing it (not ideal). I've thought about getting one of those fake rocks to cover it, but that still doesn't seal it, and tape (the other idea) doesn't really do much to prevent the weed eater from getting those wire-bundles and destroying them.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's really only 2 ways to address this issue:

1. Do it properly and replace that section of conduit. This will require removing the wires, but it is a permanent and visually appealing fix.
2. Get a split coupling or repair clamp and solvent-weld or fasten it over the damaged area.

Repair Clamp:

[image: Repair Clamp]

Split Coupling:

[image: Split Coupling]

Answer (score 1):

What you consider "not ideal" is the correct method, but when you replace it, use Schedule 80 rather than schedule 40 (what this looks to be), it's much more resistant to damage. Or rigid (which is effectively rather well-galvanized iron pipe.)

For a hack job since this is presumably low voltage and a hack job might be OK, choose a section of larger diameter conduit, slit it and (probably) apply heat (boiling water, hot air gun) to allow popping it over the current conduit. "Simply snapping it in place" is generally not "simple" as it is not *that* flexible. Polyethylene (water well pipe) might be another option for that approach.